# Neo4j Desktop 1.1.6 has blank Favorites

Tags: neo4j

I updated Neo4j Desktop from 1.1.5 to 1.1.6 on macOS High Sierra(10.13.5).
After installation I can't open Favorites correct.
I'm seeing only blank window.

Answer (score 0):

I backuped Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop and Restart Neo4j Desktop 1.1.6.
Neo4j Desktop creates new Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop.
After that I can open Favorites correctly.